# change drupal comment

Tags: drupal, layout, drupal-6, drupal-comments

I want to put the comment textarea which is used to enter the comment text above the three fields (name, email, homepage). The final result should be as shown below:

```
 the comment text area

name:      email:     homepage:     submitcomment
```

how I position the fields like this? Thank you.

the version is drupal 6.20. i mean the form to create a comment.

Comment: Are you talking about the form to create a comment, or the display of the comment after it's been created? Also, what version of Drupal?

Comment: the version is drupal 6.20. i mean the form to create a comment. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the comment form the way you want to you're probably going to want to use a hook_form_alter() to modify the formfield weights. You can theme it with by providing a preprocess function (see: http://systemseed.com/blog/how-customise-comment-form-drupal-6) but to rearrange the formfield weights I think you'll need to use hook_form_alter() in a little custom module.

Something like this:

in MY_MODULE.module

```
/**  
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().  
 */  

function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'comment_form'){
    $form['comment_filter']['#weight'] => -10
    );
  }
}
```

Other than that you could resort to something simpler with jQuery to just rearrange divs on page load

Comment: i put the '#weight' => -10  to the core file comment.module, there is no change to the form's field order. why? how to use  jQuery to change the order? could you give me an example.thank you.

Comment: edited it to show what should actually work, the comment body & the filter choices are in the same wrapper array, so you form_alter() yourself some control over the entire ['comment_filter'] section